# Check file creation time in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, file-attributes

I'm wondering if anybody knows a generic way in Jenkins pipeline to find out the creation time of a file? There are operations to touch a file but seemingly not for reading that time.

What I actually want to do is to clean out workspaces every few days - for most of our builds, we want incremental behaviour and thus don't clean out. However, there are times things build up and we'd like to be able to automatically clean out on occasion.

I need the code to work on both Linux flavours and Windows. My only big idea to date is to actually write the time into a file and read that back. However, it somehow seems wrong!